# Can I create an index on a computed column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, calculated-columns

My table has this structure.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Word] (
    [WordId]       VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
    [CategoryId]   INT          DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([WordId] ASC),
);
```

What I would like to do is to add a column called `Ascii` with a definition as `(ASCII([WordId]))`

Is there a way that I can add this and then create an index on this column + WordId + CategoryId ?  Also can I do this and have it automatically updated based on the data I already have existing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that by making the computed column `persisted`

From [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979(v=sql.105).aspx)

> Specifies that the SQL Server Database Engine will physically store
>   the computed values in the table, and update the values when any other
>   columns on which the computed column depends are updated. Marking a
>   computed column as PERSISTED lets you create an index on a computed
>   column that is deterministic

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Word] 
(
    [WordId]       VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
    [CategoryId]   INT          DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
    [Ascii]        as (ASCII([WordId])) persisted,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([WordId] ,[CategoryId],[Ascii] ),
);
```

To alter the table with addition of computed column use this

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Word] ADD [Ascii] AS (ASCII([WordId])) persisted;
```

Comment: Thanks.  Can you tell me how I can alter the table? Will it when it changes the table check the data that is already there?

Comment: @SamanthaJ - Updated. For the existing records also the `ASCII` value will be populated in computed column